# Rotating Proxy Threads In Python API Scraper

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy, python-requests

I have a scraper that uses multithreaded rotating proxies. The program works great however I was wonder what I could do to make it run faster. Currently I run it on my home router and a VPS, I notice the program runs much faster on my VPS.

I was wondering why this was the case? Is this based on GPU, Bandwith, Allowed Concurrent Connections By The ISP, amount of open threads allowed by proxyrack?

My end goal is to be able to run 10,000+ threads a second.

I have tried purchasing more threads on proxyrack but it just maxes out around 2000/5000. The support told me my threads close quickly.